# conditionally remove a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to remove the column in which there is an "o"

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    o    o    o
2 Var1    o    o
3    o Var2    o
4 Var1 Var2    o
5    o    o    o 
6 Var1    o    o
7    o Var2    o
8 Var1 Var2    o
```

The problem is that I have several tables and the position of the column that contains the "o" is different in each data frame. I would like to know a way to conditionally remove the columns with "o", since in the different tables the column is in a different position. Could be by evaluating the first row since the whole column is full of "o".

The output would look like

```
  Var1 Var2 
1    o    o    
2 Var1    o    
3    o Var2    
4 Var1 Var2    
5    o    o     
6 Var1    o    
7    o Var2    
8 Var1 Var2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    select(where(~any(. != "o")))
  Var1 Var2
1    o    o
2 Var1    o
3    o Var2
4 Var1 Var2
5    o    o
6 Var1    o
7    o Var2
8 Var1 Var2
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df1[!!colSums(df1 != "o")]
  Var1 Var2
1    o    o
2 Var1    o
3    o Var2
4 Var1 Var2
5    o    o
6 Var1    o
7    o Var2
8 Var1 Var2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("o", "Var1", "o", "Var1", "o", "Var1", 
"o", "Var1"), Var2 = c("o", "o", "Var2", "Var2", "o", "o", "Var2", 
"Var2"), Var3 = c("o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need

`df[,colMeans(df=="o")<1]`

that is remove all columns which have all 'o's?

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of options -

1. Base R `Filter`.

```
res <- Filter(function(x) any(x != 'o'), df)
res

#  Var1 Var2
#1    o    o
#2 Var1    o
#3    o Var2
#4 Var1 Var2
#5    o    o
#6 Var1    o
#7    o Var2
#8 Var1 Var2
```

2. Using `purrr`s `keep` and `discard` -

```
purrr::keep(df, ~any(.x != 'o'))
purrr::discard(df, ~all(.x == 'o'))
```